# web2py - python

Tags: csv, web2py

I'm developing an application using web2py, and I want to generate a csv file so that the columns becomes rows.

e.g: The file is generated as:

```
  name    mobile    email    Address
  yyy     yyyyy      yyy     yyyyy
```

I want the file to be generated as the following design:

```
name      yyy
mobile    yyyy
email     yyyyyy
Address   yyyy
```

How can I do this?

I used this code to generate the csv file:

```
import gluon.contenttype
response.headers['Content-Type'] = \
    gluon.contenttype.contenttype('.csv')
response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=members_approaching_renewal_report.csv'\   rows=db().select(db.member.membership_id,db.member.first_name,db.member.middle_name,db.member.last_name,db.member.birthdate,db.member.membership_status,db.member.registration_date,db.member.membership_end_date)
rows.colnames=('Membership Id','First Name','Middle Name','Last Name','Birthday Date','Membership Status','Registration Date','Membership ending Date')
return str(rows)
```

How should I edit this code to make what I want?

Answer (score 6):

If your results are in a list of lists called `results`, and your header titles are in a list called `headers` you can transpose it like this:

```
transposed = zip(headers, *results)
```

Then output as normal, with something like:

```
import csv
csv_writer = csv.writer(filename)
csv_writer.writerows(transposed)
```

Comment: i don't use this method to generate by this way deeply when i have records returned from database

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand.  This method should regardless of the source of the records.

Comment: i have

rows=db().select(db.member.membership_id,db.member.first_name,db.member.middle_name,db.member.last_name,db.member.birthdate,db.member.membership_status,db.member.registration_date,db.member.membership_end_date)
rows.colnames=('Membership Id','First Name','Middle Name','Last Name','Birthday Date','Membership Status','Registration Date','Membership ending Date')

How can use "rows" to be displayed into csv file?? 
--> i used gluon method but i cant transpose the file if you know another methode could you please tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what gluon is.  If you can get your results into a list of lists, then you can use my method.  If you can't, could you tell me what format it is?